# Monitoring UUIDs of MariaDB servers in Galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

I want to be able to monitor the UUIDS of several MariaDB servers on a regular basis to make sure that they haven't somehow been removed from the cluster. I have a command that I run to retrieve it locally: `mysql -umaria -e "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_state_uuid'"`. I would like to be able to run this remotely somehow from one of the servers in the cluster that can compare its UUID to those of the rest of the servers. Unfortunately, I can't simply connect via remote shell so I need it to use commands found on the server already. The servers are all running RHEL 7 x64.

Comment: `mysql` has the flag `-h` which allows you to specify the database server to connect to via tcp/3306 (per default). Would this be solving your problem?

Comment: I'm not going to be able to check now, I will when I have a chance. Does it have some way of supplying credentials automatically or some other way of identifying itself with the target server?

Comment: the mysql_config_editor might help you with "automatic" authentication: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html